# Visual Studio - referencing WCF Library directly and the ignoring of serviceHostingEnvironment?

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, .net-4.0

Just want to ask you to confirm that I'm right (but may be totally wrong :).

Situation: I have a VS2010 Solution with 3 projects A) WCF Library, B) Web Site that host this library C) test application that use the web service. Last I could configure two different ways: adding reference to the WCF Lib or Web Site.

I've discovered that when I'm referencing WCF library directly (some may be remember those endpoints http://localhost:8732/**Design_Time_Addresses**/...)  the configuration of custom **servicehostfactory** in app.config element

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment><serviceActivations>..
```

is ignored.

Since interpretation of serviceHostingEnvironment is responsibility of the host I make an assumption that VS2010 WCF Library Host have such feature - ignore serviceHostingEnvironment? Am I right?

P.S. May be I could ask you to point me the doc where I could find the information about VS2010 WCF library's host.. It seems I should get to know better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description of test service host is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552363.aspx). `ServiceHostingEnvironment` element controls integration with web server = I don't think that any part of this configuration section is used for self hosted services and test host is self hosting.

`ServiceActivations` element contains file-less activation configuration for web server. That means ability to activate service without physical existence of hosting .svc file. That is something which doesn't make sense in self hosted scenario.

Comment: For "self hosted" yes it is clear. But I've expected that wcfsvchost supports ServiceHostingEnvironment for debug purposes. Just glad to know that I can explain what I see right way.